# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Student ID = 'EO001' AND Password = 'apples''

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, authentication

I am coding a login form in Visual Basics 2010 Express and I keep having this error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Student ID = 'EO001' AND Password = 'apples''.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmStudentLogin


    Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0;data source=C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Database.accdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login Student WHERE Student ID = '" & txtLogin.Text & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' If the record can be queried, Pass verification and open another form.  
        If (sdr.Read() = True) Then
            MsgBox("Welcome")
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid user / pass")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is `Student` an *alias* for `Login`? if so: `Student.ID` or if its a field with a space make it `[Student ID]`. Also you are open to SQL injection

Comment: If someone's password is "' OR '' = '" you'll have a problem. Use parameters, don't concatonate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Login Student] WHERE [Student ID] = '" & txtLogin.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", con)
```

Yuo have to remember that if you have spaces in the table/column names, you need to wrap them with square brackets.

So

```
SELECT [Column] FROM [Table] Where [Where] = 0 ORDER BY [Order]
```

Comment: That was the problem, thank you so much! I've been stuck on that for weeks!